# R - expand.grid only within levels of one variable

Tags: r

I have a dataset similar to:

**Site Sample Date:**

```
A   A1 2016-09-01 
A   A1 2016-09-21 
A   A2 2016-09-15 
A   A2 2016-09-21 
B   B1 2016-09-03 
B   B2 2016-09-12
```

What I would like to do is expand.grid, but only within each level of df$Site to acheive this:

**Site  Sample  Date:**

```
A   A1  2016-09-01
A   A1  2016-09-15
A   A1  2016-09-21
A   A2  2016-09-01
A   A2  2016-09-15
A   A2  2016-09-21
B   B1  2016-09-03
B   B1  2016-09-12
B   B2  2016-09-03
B   B2  2016-09-12
```

But I don't know how to specify that with expand.grid so I don't end up with:

**Site  Sample  Date:**

```
A   A1  2016-09-01
A   A1  2016-09-03
A   A1  2016-09-12
A   A1  2016-09-15
A   A1  2016-09-21
A   A2  2016-09-01
A   A2  2016-09-03
A   A2  2016-09-12
A   A2  2016-09-15
A   A2  2016-09-21
B   B1  2016-09-01
B   B1  2016-09-03
B   B1  2016-09-12
B   B1  2016-09-15
B   B1  2016-09-21
B   B2  2016-09-01
B   B2  2016-09-03
B   B2  2016-09-12
B   B2  2016-09-15
B   B2  2016-09-21
```

I hope this is clear, I couldn't figure out how to format these tables very well!

Comment: Hi, please post the code that you have tried.

Comment: Column headers would help to. I'm pretty sure the column with `2016-09-01` *isn't* the `site` column, but is the column with `A` or `A1` the site column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this after grouping by 'Site' with `dplyr/tidyr'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Site) %>%
   expand(Sample, Date)
#    Site Sample       Date
#   <chr>  <chr>      <chr>
#1      A     A1 2016-09-01
#2      A     A1 2016-09-15
#3      A     A1 2016-09-21
#4      A     A2 2016-09-01
#5      A     A2 2016-09-15
#6      A     A2 2016-09-21
#7      B     B1 2016-09-03
#8      B     B1 2016-09-12
#9      B     B2 2016-09-03
#10     B     B2 2016-09-12
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, do.call(CJ, lapply(.SD, unique)) , by = Site]
#    Site Sample       Date
# 1:    A     A1 2016-09-01
# 2:    A     A1 2016-09-15
# 3:    A     A1 2016-09-21
# 4:    A     A2 2016-09-01
# 5:    A     A2 2016-09-15
# 6:    A     A2 2016-09-21
# 7:    B     B1 2016-09-03
# 8:    B     B1 2016-09-12
# 9:    B     B2 2016-09-03
#10:    B     B2 2016-09-12
```

---

Or we can use a `base R` solution

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df1[-1], df1$Site), 
         function(x) expand.grid(lapply(x, unique))))
#   Sample       Date
#A.1     A1 2016-09-01
#A.2     A2 2016-09-01
#A.3     A1 2016-09-21
#A.4     A2 2016-09-21
#A.5     A1 2016-09-15
#A.6     A2 2016-09-15
#B.1     B1 2016-09-03
#B.2     B2 2016-09-03
#B.3     B1 2016-09-12
#B.4     B2 2016-09-12
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Site = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), Sample = c("A1", 
"A1", "A2", "A2", "B1", "B2"), Date = c("2016-09-01", "2016-09-21", 
"2016-09-15", "2016-09-21", "2016-09-03", "2016-09-12")), .Names = c("Site", 
"Sample", "Date"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: The dplyr/tidyr solution seems the most straightforward, but running that code gives me even bigger expansion (40 rows, it's making lines for samples B1, B2 within site A for e.g.) instead of the 10 row solution I'm looking for.  I copied the code exactly a you had it, I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @RB78  Based on your example, I get only 10 rows as output.  I updated with the data used

Comment: @RB78 I am using `tidyr_0.6.0` and  `dplyr_0.5.0`

Comment: The issue was that I had the variables in my df1 as factors, so all of the levels were being retained and expanded.  When I changed them to character format, I got the 10 row solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution. You can feed `expand.grid` unique vectors like this

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Site),
               function(i) with(i, expand.grid(unique(Site), unique(Sample), unique(Date)))))

Var1 Var2       Var3
A.1    A   A1 2016-09-01
A.2    A   A2 2016-09-01
A.3    A   A1 2016-09-21
A.4    A   A2 2016-09-21
A.5    A   A1 2016-09-15
A.6    A   A2 2016-09-15
B.1    B   B1 2016-09-03
B.2    B   B2 2016-09-03
B.3    B   B1 2016-09-12
B.4    B   B2 2016-09-12
```

or use `unique` on each expanded data.frame.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$Site),
                     function(i) with(i, unique(expand.grid(Site, Sample, Date)))))
     Var1 Var2       Var3
A.1     A   A1 2016-09-01
A.9     A   A2 2016-09-01
A.17    A   A1 2016-09-21
A.25    A   A2 2016-09-21
A.33    A   A1 2016-09-15
A.41    A   A2 2016-09-15
B.1     B   B1 2016-09-03
B.3     B   B2 2016-09-03
B.5     B   B1 2016-09-12
B.7     B   B2 2016-09-12
```

Comment: This solution is repeating rows (A.3,A.4 and A.7,A.8 are the same).  I'm looking to generate a 10 row solution as above.

Comment: OK. Missed that. I threw in an additional `unique` to my first solution and added a second one that is shorter but produces data.frames with more duplicates and then drops the duplicates.